# Can't Create Event Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i wanna create a HOVER event for meta "a" in this code in order to change its background color but it doesnt seem to work, i dont really know what im missing, here it is:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $("#admin_symbol").hover(function(){
   $("#header_div2").css("background-color","black");
  },
  function(){
   $("#header_div2").css("background-color","#222222"); 
  }
  );
    
  $("#sub_menu_admin").hide();
  $("#admin_symbol").click(function(){   
   $("#sub_menu_admin").slideToggle(); 
  })
  
        <!-- i create it here -->
  $(".class_admin").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
  }
  ,
  function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","white");
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
     <div id="header_div1">
         Quảng trị hệ thống
        </div>
        <div id="header_div2">
         <ul>
             <li id="admin_symbol"><span id="admin_welcome">&nbspXin chào: Admin</span></li>
                <ul id="sub_menu_admin">
                 <li  id ="admin_prolife"><a class="class_admin" id ="admin_a1" href="#"><img id="admin_prolife_symbol" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-with-laptop/100/user-laptop-512.png">&nbsp Prolife</a></li>
                    <li  id="admin_changepw"><a class="class_admin" id ="admin_a2" href="#"><img id="admin_changepw_symbol" src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/setting2.png"> &nbsp Đổi mật khẩu</a></li>
                    <li  id="admin_logout"><a class="class_admin" id ="admin_a3" href="#"><img id="admin_logout_symbol" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements/700/012_power-512.png">&nbsp Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In Case this could help :

+My full project: https://jsfiddle.net/HiepNguyen/do7nsyr5/93/

i did try create a hover event with CSS but no luck.
i appreciate every help.

**[Update]**: i have figured out that when i use my code on jsfiddle it runs fine, but when i run it on local, the sub menu items will not change its background color as i want, still dont know why.

Comment: this is your code running as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkeqan5y/4/

Comment: could you tell more about the behavior that you need? as I can see the hover is working nicely.

Comment: when i hover on any META "A" in this code i want it changes its background-color-thats all, my side doesnt work at all

Comment: have you checked the jsfiddle link above? is that what you want but locally? or you need another behavior? I'm asking since I can see that I can see on jsfiddle that the menu header with the following text `Xin chào: Admin` gets a black background when you hover over it. so is this the behavior or you need that but for the menu items?

Comment: wow mate how does it run AS I WANT on jsfiddle , im confused, when i run it on local the menu items didnt change its background color, is it because of jquery version?

Comment: If it runs in your fiddle then you've obviously not included something in your example. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: i've uploaded my project on jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/HiepNguyen/do7nsyr5/97/        the problem doesnt appear till i add some more html , please have a look if you have time, thank u

Comment: i can't keep the sub menu showing when i move my mouse down - the Hover event which i declare for ".class_admin" doesnt trigger

Comment: nvm i made it run correctly, thank you for your time one me sir. i really appreciate your kind